# VBA and references to objects

Tags: vba, reference, lifetime

I'm clueless to how the [Set statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) works in VBA.

Below a test method where b is set as a reference to the a object. Then a object is set to nothing.
This should also affect the b object, since it also refers to the same object. But nevertheless, the b object is still intact and can display the Collection. How is this possible?

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim a As Collection
    Dim b As Collection

    Set a = New Collection

    a.Add "High", "one"
    a.Add "Five", "two"
    a.Add "!", "three"

    Set b = a

    Debug.Print a.Item("one") & " " & a.Item("two") & a.Item("three")

    Set a = Nothing

    Debug.Print b.Item("one") & " " & b.Item("two") & b.Item("three")

    Set b = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Because it is a _pointer_. [This](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-objects/#VBA_Objects_in_Memory) might be helpful.

Comment: "Generally, when you use Set to assign an object reference to a variable, no copy of the object is created for that variable. Instead, a reference to the object is created. More than one object variable can refer to the same object. Because such variables are references to the object rather than copies of the object, any change in the object is reflected in all variables that refer to it."

Comment: but what's your actual issue? why do you want two object variables pointing at the same object and why do you want to set one variable to nothing and have the other one (possibly) be set to nothing too?

Comment: @BigBen Exactly! So why is the change in the a object (Set a = Nothing) not reflected in the b object?

Comment: `a` and `b` are both *references* to the same collection... `Set a = Nothing` [*disassociates*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/nothing-keyword) `a` from the collection, but `b` still refers to it.

Comment: You have two variables a and b which contain the address of the collection in memory. They both point to the same address. If you set one variable to nothing the other one still points to the address of the collection in memory.

Comment: I'm humbled and ashamed. Of course! Set a = Nothing doesn't affect the real object, just the reference.

Comment: Yes, no need to be ashamend and he will not be the last one. Once I was one of them as well.

Comment: @HTH Yes, this is a pointless scenario. I have a real world problem including factory methods and singleton objects, and this is just a simplification of the core problem. I couldn't understand why the object continued to live on in the caller functions, although I forced them to "detruct" in the factory by setting them to `Nothing`.

Comment: @JohanA, I see. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion is more around what `Set a = Nothing` does.

From the [`Nothing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/nothing-keyword) docs:

> The **Nothing** keyword is used to disassociate an object variable from an actual object.
>
> ...
>
> Several object variables can refer to the same actual object. When **Nothing** is assigned to an object variable, that variable no longer refers to an actual object.
>
> When several object variables refer to the same object, memory and system resources associated with the object to which the variables refer are released only after all of them have been set to **Nothing**, either explicitly by using **Set**, or implicitly after the last object variable referencing the actual object goes out of scope

`a` and `b` both reference the same collection. After `Set a = Nothing`, `b` still references the unchanged collection.